# Azure Communication Services Web Calling in Blazor - issues with npm

Tags: node.js, azure-communication-services

I'm trying to use Azure Communications Service for web calling.  Looks like the only examples I can find require node.js.  I'm getting errors with npm.  I'm very new with npm.  I'm getting hundreds of errors with the base error being "error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier"

Here is my package.json

```
  "name": "npmjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "build": "webpack ./src/index.js --output-path ../wwwroot --output-filename index.bundle.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/communication-calling": "^1.4.4",
    "@azure/communication-common": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Using the JS library for calling for a web app is the right approach. Although, there is a NuGet package for .NET, it's meant for desktop apps (UWP etc.)
1) Are you using Blazor WebAssembly App or Blazor Server App? 2) Can you share steps to reproduce, or better, the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a blank typescript file to the src directory.  I named it index.ts. After this change, the program started compiling correctly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).